# ASP.NET MVC 3 Allow intranet site access based on AD group

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to allow site wide access to my intranet site based on an AD group without having to use the `[Authorize]` attibute on every controller?

I am using Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `AuthorizeAttribute` to the global filters collection, as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx).

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

It is usually *not* a good idea to use the Web.config `authorization` element for this since this [restricts file-based access](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/04/18/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous.aspx). But when you protect your entire site, using the Web.config file will work just as well.

Answer (score 3):

In webconfig use

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="groupname"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
 </system.web>
```

Comment: Yes I already have this in my web.config, what I would like also is to restrict access to only an active directory security group.

Comment: I update my answer. instead of groupname write the name of security group

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It still allows access to user who is not a member of the AD group.

Comment: sorry my bad...i did not change it to *

Comment: It did help thank you Kirill however I prefer Ronald's answer.

Answer (score 0):

## IIS 7 & IIS 8

1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to your website.
2. In Features View, double-click Authentication.
3. On the Authentication page, select Windows authentication. If Windows authentication is not an option, you'll need to make sure Windows authentication is installed on the server.

**To enable Windows authentication on Windows:**

a) In Control Panel open "Programs and Features".

b) Select "Turn Windows features on or off".

c) Navigate to Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Security and make sure the Windows authentication node is checked.

**To enable Windows authentication on Windows Server:**

a) In Server Manager, select Web Server (IIS) and click Add Role Services

b) Navigate to Web Server > Security and make sure the Windows authentication node is checked.

***Finally***

1. In the Actions pane, click Enable to use Windows authentication.
2. On the Authentication page, select Anonymous authentication.
3. In the Actions pane, click Disable to disable anonymous authentication.

## IIS Express

1. Right click on the project in Visual Studio and select Use IIS Express.
2. Click on your project in the Solution Explorer to select the project.
3. If the Properties pane is not open, open it (F4).
4. In the Properties pane for your project:

   a) Set "Anonymous Authentication" to "Disabled".

   b) Set "Windows Authentication" to "Enabled".